# Discord.js Animated Emojis

Tags: discord.js, emoji

I have a bot, and I want to use it to send a animated emoji.
I have the emoji ID, `<:rgb_lego:993606148580184154>`
but whenever I make it send the message, it just says

```
Pong!  The round trip took 76ms. ⚡:rgb_lego:
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what server (guild) you sent it and how exactly you do it.

Guess you need to check & fetch the requested custom emojie from server and then sent it.

You might wanna [check Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Emoji) docs for that. But if I remember it correctly, emojies should be accessed by bot via:

`client.guild.emojis.[methodName]` via [`GuildEmojiManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildEmojiManager)

The second problem could be relevant to the server, where you want to sent it, doesn't have the required emojie, so in that case it has been delivered as a text ref, not an emojie itself or the bot account doesn't have premium features required for using emojies or so on.